# My Bezier curve code is too slow. How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, optimization, bezier

I wrote this simple code:

```
public static class Bezier
{
    private static Vector2 GetInterpolatedPoint(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, float t)
    {
        return new Vector2(a.X * (1f - t) + b.X * t, a.Y * (1f - t) + b.Y * t);
    }

    public static Vector2 GetPoint(IList<Vector2> points, float t)
    {
        int initialCount = points.Count;
        Vector2[] buf;
        while (points.Count > 2)
        {
            buf = new Vector2[points.Count-1];
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                buf[i] = GetInterpolatedPoint(points[i], points[i + 1], t);
            }
            points = buf;
        }

        return GetInterpolatedPoint(points[0], points[1], t);
    }

}
```

**Input:**

- List of 100 random 2D points
- 0.0001f step (10 000 iterations)

**Result:**

- Calculated in ~1200ms.

It's **too slow** for my project. How can I improve this result? I need any tips for this code improvement or another way to calculate it more effective.

Comment: Such a question is much better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, one thing that jumped into my eye is your code excessively allocating new arrays. Try finding a way where you use (and reuse) only one array instance to avoid all those array allocations...

Comment: Stop reallocating the points array and re-slice a span.

Comment: I assume `Vector2` is, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2?view=net-6.0?

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: How are you calculating the time taken? I tried it in release build on my PC and it takes less than 2ms.

Comment: [This was my test code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/laoeHC) (run locally, so results differ from online times)

Comment: @Jodrell, Vector2 from System.Numerics

Comment: Do you *really* need that small a step?

Comment: @MatthewWatson StopWatch. Before and after cycle with Bezier.GetPoint(...)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, I need. In my project this curve can be very long. And I need support of ~100 points in one curve.

Comment: Why on earth are you using _ten thousand_ steps per curve? Pick a step size that is appropriate to the size of the curve. At most normal screen scales, 64 steps is already overkill for a cubic curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the most recent versions of C# it's possible to significantly speed this up.

You can do so in a few ways:

- Use `Span<T>` and `stackalloc` to avoid heap allocations.
- Reuse that span so that only one memory allocation is needed. This requires maintaining the count of values as a separate variable.
- Specify the `Vector2` parameters for `getInterpolatedPoint()` as `in`.

Putting those together (and renaming the methods to have an `Opt` suffix):

```
public static class Bezier
{
    static Vector2 getInterpolatedPointOpt(in Vector2 a, in Vector2 b, float t)
    {
        return new Vector2(a.X * (1f - t) + b.X * t, a.Y * (1f - t) + b.Y * t);
    }

    public static Vector2 GetPointOpt(IList<Vector2> points, float t)
    {
        int count = points.Count;
        Span<Vector2> array = stackalloc Vector2[count]; // Not suitable for large arrays.

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            array[i] = getInterpolatedPointOpt(points[i], points[i + 1], t);
        }

        while (--count > 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                array[i] = getInterpolatedPointOpt(array[i], array[i + 1], t);
            }
        }

        return getInterpolatedPointOpt(array[0], array[1], t);
    }
}
```

The separate loop for the first iteration uses the original data and the loop for the remaining iterations uses the span. This avoids copying the original data before interpolating it.

I wrote the following test code, but you should use Benchmark.Net for proper timings (this test code assumes that the original unoptimised methods are still in the class):

```
Random rng = new Random(123445);

Vector2[] buff = new Vector2[10000];

var sw = new Stopwatch();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < buff.Length; ++j)
    {
        buff[j].X = rng.NextSingle();
        buff[j].Y = rng.NextSingle();
    }

    sw.Restart();
    Vector2 result1 = Bezier.GetPointOpt(buff, 0.0001f);

    Console.WriteLine("GetPointOpt() took " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    sw.Restart();

    Vector2 result2 = Bezier.GetPoint(buff, 0.0001f);

    Console.WriteLine("GetPoint() took " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    Console.WriteLine(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output (run in release mode):

```
GetPointOpt() took 107.5646
GetPoint() took 631.597
<0.49709368, 0.55904883>
<0.49709368, 0.55904883>

GetPointOpt() took 95.9445
GetPoint() took 502.4843
<0.5745254, 0.48695806>
<0.5745254, 0.48695806>

GetPointOpt() took 99.6847
GetPoint() took 507.7098
<0.59854025, 0.4798301>
<0.59854025, 0.4798301>

GetPointOpt() took 94.5894
GetPoint() took 480.0481
<0.4043915, 0.3434864>
<0.4043915, 0.3434864>

GetPointOpt() took 96.8213
GetPoint() took 481.8792
<0.4802326, 0.5464641>
<0.4802326, 0.5464641>

GetPointOpt() took 92.3702
GetPoint() took 478.834
<0.64281195, 0.72084826>
<0.64281195, 0.72084826>

GetPointOpt() took 109.5258
GetPoint() took 507.9398
<0.5327367, 0.6595588>
<0.5327367, 0.6595588>

GetPointOpt() took 92.3229
GetPoint() took 474.3246
<0.5084992, 0.57937586>
<0.5084992, 0.57937586>

GetPointOpt() took 107.6864
GetPoint() took 479.8337
<0.25628412, 0.6602504>
<0.25628412, 0.6602504>

GetPointOpt() took 98.2489
GetPoint() took 500.7994
<0.71759677, 0.50711>
<0.71759677, 0.50711>
```

This optimised code runs approximately five times faster.

---

Addendum 1: Benchmark.NET test code:

```
public class UnderTest
{
    public UnderTest()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _buff.Length; ++j)
        {
            _buff[j].X = _rng.NextSingle();
            _buff[j].Y = _rng.NextSingle();
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void Unoptimised()
    {
        Bezier.GetPoint(_buff, 0.0001f);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Optimised()
    {
        Bezier.GetPointOpt(_buff, 0.0001f);
    }

    readonly Random    _rng  = new Random(123445);
    readonly Vector2[] _buff = new Vector2[10000];
}
```

Results:

```
|      Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
|------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|--------:|
| Unoptimised | 459.6 ms | 11.03 ms | 32.35 ms | 451.0 ms |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|   Optimised | 106.8 ms |  2.13 ms |  3.79 ms | 106.5 ms |  0.22 |    0.02 |
```

---

Addendum 2: Write the `getInterpolatedPoint()` method inline.

It looks like this:

```
public static Vector2 GetPointOpt(IList<Vector2> points, float t)
{
    int count = points.Count;
    Span<Vector2> array = stackalloc Vector2[count]; // Not suitable for large arrays.

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
        array[i].X = points[i].X * (1f - t) + points[i + 1].X * t;
        array[i].Y = points[i].Y * (1f - t) + points[i + 1].Y * t;
    }

    while (--count > 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            array[i].X = array[i].X * (1f - t) + array[i + 1].X * t;
            array[i].Y = array[i].Y * (1f - t) + array[i + 1].Y * t;
        }
    }

    return new Vector2(
        array[0].X * (1f - t) + array[1].X * t,
        array[0].Y * (1f - t) + array[1].Y * t);
}
```

However, the improvement from writing this inline is very marginal, which probably speaks to the effectiveness of the JIT compiler, which is likely already inlining the `getInterpolatedPoint()` method.

Results:

```
|      Method |      Mean |    Error |    StdDev | Ratio |
|------------ |----------:|---------:|----------:|------:|
| Unoptimised | 437.18 ms | 8.635 ms | 13.186 ms |  1.00 |
|   Optimised |  77.90 ms | 1.546 ms |  3.735 ms |  0.18 |
```

The ratio is 0.18 rather than 0.22 - a marginal improvement of around 20% faster than calling `getInterpolatedPoint()`.

Comment: Thank you! For a small number of points, the efficiency is much higher. For a large amount, the effect is also noticeable, but not so much. It looks like I will have to severely limit the amount of input data. Or figure/find out how to simplify the complexity of the algorithm without a strong loss of accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have no idea about the theory of calculating Bezier curves, so I'm just assuming your math is correct, the way you are doing it. But it seems like your whole calculation can be done inplace instead of always creating new arrays. Ie, create a copy of your list first, and then work on this copy, considering one element less in each iteration, until you are down to only 2 elements ...

```
public static class Bezier
{
    private static Vector2 GetInterpolatedPoint(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, float t)
    {
        return new Vector2(a.X * (1f - t) + b.X * t, a.Y * (1f - t) + b.Y * t);
    }

    public static Vector2 GetPoint(IList<Vector2> points, float t)
    {
        //Make a SHALLOW copy of your list
        var copy = points.ToList(); 
        for (int upper = copy.Count; upper > 2; upper--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < upper - 1; i++)
            {
                copy[i] = GetInterpolatedPoint(copy[i], copy[i + 1], t);
            }
        }

        return GetInterpolatedPoint(copy[0], copy[1], t);
    }

}
```

And if you want to reduce the number of created `Vector2` objects, you could even refactor you `GetInterpolatedPoint` to manipulate one of the given vectors instead of returing a new one. But this may considered bad style ... Of course for this, you would also need to create a DEEP COPY of your initial list of points.

```
public static class Bezier
{
    private static void GetInterpolatedPoint(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, float t)
    {
        a.X = a.X * (1f - t) + b.X * t;
        a.Y = a.Y * (1f - t) + b.Y * t
    }

    public static Vector2 GetPoint(IList<Vector2> points, float t)
    {
        //make a DEEP copy of your list (ie copy all Vectors)
        var copy = points.Select(x => new Vector2(x.X, x.Y)).ToList(); 
        for (int upper = copy.Count; upper > 2; upper--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < upper - 1; i++)
            {
                GetInterpolatedPoint(copy[i], copy[i + 1], t);
            }
        }

        GetInterpolatedPoint(copy[0], copy[1], t);
        return copy[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like a very smart way to calculate exactly this algorithm. I don't need to even copy something, It is enough to simply change the elements of the array.. It will be a great improvement. I can't upvote this (my reputation less than 15), sorry.